# Listbox items represented as icons?

Tags: windows, powershell, user-interface, listbox

Im building sort of 'app store' which our workers will be able to run and install programs on their computers only from the allowd list.

one of things i like to do is to take this listbox

```
$ListBox1                        = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ListBox
#$ListBox1.text                   = "listBox"
$ListBox1.width                  = 240
$ListBox1.height                 = 330
@('Program1','Program2','Program3') | ForEach-Object {[void] $ListBox1.Items.Add($_)}
$ListBox1.location               = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(57,90)
$listbox1.SelectionMode          = 'MultiExtended'
```

and have it represented with icons so the user wont see just like program 1 program 2 and so on..
i thought about adding buttons for program1 program2 and so on but i dont like the idea that the user will need to press button and install it. i would like him to select all the programs he want and then a next button so everything he chose will be installed.

can i achive this with powershell?

Comment: Yes - just pass the selected list of items to your installation functions

Comment: Im not sure i understand what you mean